# Why is there a Null Pointer Exception being thrown for this bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, nullpointerexception, client-server

I have a client code that creates a socket and then receives images from the server. The client then uses a thread to make the application's image view and bitmap. However, every time I try to run the application I get a null pointer exception on the line where the bitmap is created from the input stream of the socket. Here is the code for the thread:
     class DataWorker extends Thread{

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
        try {
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(socket.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        uiHandler.post(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                imageIn.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the line where the exception is being thrown.

```
 bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

Any insight as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the debugger?

Comment: It looks like `socket` is `null`. I would check into why that could be

Answer (score 2):

Either your socket is null, or its returning a null input stream.  Check both for null to figure out which.  As defensive programming you may want to not call that function if so, but you should probably go back to the code that creates the socket and figure out what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

can't makes comments so:
I don't know but just guessing I would say the socket is null... 
Sarajog